# Filtering a pandas data frame which has 2 level of column headers

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a pandas data frame which has 2 levels of columns header using a list in the fairly standard way of using `isin` and a mask to retun a new filtered dataframe. However I keep running into a value error around overlapping index names which I can't seem to solve.

Here are examples, of my list I'd like to filter on, as well as the dataframe itself. Not sure how to provide the code needed to generate this dataframe as it is imported from an csv file.

```
my_list = ['DEF', 'GHI']

+------+--------+----------+---+----------+---+
| CODE |  NAME  | STANDARD |   | ADVANCED |   |
+------+--------+----------+---+----------+---+
| CODE | NAME   | A        | B | A        | B |
+------+--------+----------+---+----------+---+
| ABC  | APPLE  | 1        | 1 | 2        | 2 |
| DEF  | BANANA | 3        | 3 | 4        | 4 |
| GHI  | KIWI   | 5        | 5 | 6        | 6 |
| JKL  | MANGO  | 7        | 7 | 8        | 8 |
+------+--------+----------+---+----------+---+
```

running the following line to filter

```
new_df = df[df['CODE'].isin(my_list)]
```

returns

```
ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names
```

however if I run `df['CODE'].isin(my_list)` by itself, this seems to work and returns the `Symbol` column with True/False values, which means something goes wrong when applying the mask to the original dataframe.

df source code

```
[{('CODE', 'CODE'): 'ABC',
  ('NAME', 'NAME'): 'APPLE',
  ('STANDARD', 'A'): 1,
  ('STANDARD', 'B'): 1,
  ('ADVANCED', 'A'): 2,
  ('ADVANCED', 'B'): 2},
 {('CODE', 'CODE'): 'DEF',
  ('NAME', 'NAME'): 'BANANA',
  ('STANDARD', 'A'): 3,
  ('STANDARD', 'B'): 3,
  ('ADVANCED', 'A'): 4,
  ('ADVANCED', 'B'): 4},
 {('CODE', 'CODE'): 'GHI',
  ('NAME', 'NAME'): 'KIWI',
  ('STANDARD', 'A'): 5,
  ('STANDARD', 'B'): 5,
  ('ADVANCED', 'A'): 6,
  ('ADVANCED', 'B'): 6},
 {('CODE', 'CODE'): 'JKL',
  ('NAME', 'NAME'): 'MANGO',
  ('STANDARD', 'A'): 7,
  ('STANDARD', 'B'): 7,
  ('ADVANCED', 'A'): 8,
  ('ADVANCED', 'B'): 8}]
```

Comment: kindly share the source code of the dataframe - > ``df.to_dict('records')``

Comment: @sammywemmy have added at the bottom. thanks for teaching how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at what `df['CODE'].isin(my_list)` produces:

```
    CODE
0  False
1   True
2   True
3  False
```

Compared to a single level index:

```
my_list = ['DEF', 'GHI']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CODE': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL']
})
print(df['CODE'].isin(my_list))
```

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: CODE, dtype: bool
```

---

Fix

Either grab the index out of CODE:

```
new_df = df[df['CODE'].isin(my_list)['CODE']]
```

Or reference the MultiIndex directly:

```
new_df = df[df[('CODE', 'CODE')].isin(my_list)]
```

Both produce:

`new_df`:

```
  CODE    NAME STANDARD    ADVANCED   
  CODE    NAME        A  B        A  B
1  DEF  BANANA        3  3        4  4
2  GHI    KIWI        5  5        6  6
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = ['DEF', 'GHI']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('CODE', 'CODE'): ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'],
    ('NAME', 'NAME'): ['APPLE', 'BANANA', 'KIWI', 'MANGO'],
    ('STANDARD', 'A'): [1, 3, 5, 7], ('STANDARD', 'B'): [1, 3, 5, 7],
    ('ADVANCED', 'A'): [2, 4, 6, 8], ('ADVANCED', 'B'): [2, 4, 6, 8]
})

new_df = df[df[('CODE', 'CODE')].isin(my_list)]
print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 3):

When there are multiple `index` I usually slice with position

```
my_list = ['DEF', 'GHI']
df.iloc[:,0].isin(my_list)
Out[49]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: (CODE, CODE), dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
df.loc[df['CODE'].isin(my_list).squeeze()]
```